How to display a Tuple response on Swagger
I have a scenario on C# where I want to generate Swagger documentation (using SwashBuckle) on a controller with this annotation
[ProducesResponseType(200, Type = typeof((bool, AddressCheckResponse)))]

The response would then be return Ok(response); which in itself has both bool and AddressCheckResponse.
Thing is, the Swagger generation tries to combine the two rather than display both separately, as such

Is there a way to get it to show the complete tuple as a response rather than it trying to combine the two?

Don't use a tuple, use a type.  Then swagger will document it correctly.

Can you check how the BooleanAddressCheckResponseValueTuple schema is defined in your generated OpenAPI YAML/JSON file? Also, what is the OpenAPI version - openapi: 3.1.0 or openapi: 3.0.x?

I just got done writing a JsonConverter for ValueTuple (a struct, and what you are using here) and Tuple (a class) in my Blazor WASM project; By default, JsonSerializer converts ValueTuple to an empty object, because the "Items" are fields and not properties . Also ValueTuples are structs, which are not nullable by default. Not sure a ValueTuple is going to give you the results you expect.

@LoneSpawn really? So a (true, "test") will be serialized to {} instead of { "item1": true, "item2": "test" } or at least [true, "test"]?

@GoodNightNerdPride Yup. Because ValueTuple.Item1 and ValueTuple.Item2 are fields and not properties. In my custom ValueTuple converter I serialize it to an array of the ValueTuple's values.

@Neil I assume that by type, you mean an object? Or something else?

@Helen I am currently using OpenAPI version 3.0.1

Yes, a type.  Define a new class with the 2 properties, and the relevant comments, change your end point to return this type, and swagger will generate things correctly.
